# Python code to download tar.gz gives UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, unicode, python-2.6, decoding

I want to download java and hence I use following command from shell and it works properly.

wget -P /data/ --no-check-certificate --no-cookies --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u79-b15/jdk-7u79-linux-x64.tar.gz

But when I run the same command using python I get an error.
Here is my python code.

```
from resource_management import *

import os
import params
cmd = 'wget -P ' + params.java_tarball_path + ' --no-check-certificate --no-cookies --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u79-b15/jdk-7u79-linux-x64.tar.gz
print cmd
Execute(cmd, user=params.monarch_user, timeout=300)
```

I get following error "File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 198, in _call
    err_msg = Logger.filter_text(("Execution of '%s' returned %d. %s") % (command_alias, code, out))
**UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 1228: ordinal not in range(128)"**

I also printed my command to execute in python, it looks ok to me.
"wget -P /data/ --no-check-certificate --no-cookies --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u79-b15/jdk-7u79-linux-x64.tar.gz"

How can I download using python's Execute command?

Comment: You've tagged your question as `python-2.7`, but the error is showing `python-2.6`.  Also, what is the `resource_management` module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go with `urllib2` or `requests` instead of using `Execute`.

```
import urllib2
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders.append(('Cookie', 'oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie'))
f = opener.open('http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u79-b15/jdk-7u79-linux-x64.tar.gz')
with open('jdk-7u79-linux-x64.tar.gz', 'w+') as save:
     save.write(f.read())
```

Comment: This works for me. Just another question I want to download java to /work location, how do I do it using above code?

Comment: Either execute the code in that directory or adjust the open() to '/work/java.tar.gz'. Could you the answer as 'answer'?

Comment: Note that the above code requires ~150Mb RAM because the downloaded file is read in one chunk.

Answer (score 0):

The stacktrace is pretty explicit. The call to `Logger.filter_text` raises a `UnicodeError`. It's probably because `out` is a unicode. Demo:

```
>>> "%s %s" % ("é", "é")   # works
'\xc3\xa9 \xc3\xa9'
>>> "%s %s" % ("é", u"é")  # doesn't work
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

You might want to modify the code in resource_management/core/shell.py and convert the `out` variable to str:

```
Logger.filter_text(("Execution of '%s' returned %d. %s") % (command_alias, code, out.decode("utf-8")))
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug in `resource_management` module that mixes bytestrings and Unicode text. To workaround it, you could download the tarball yourself:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import os
import urllib2
from contextlib import closing
from shutil import copyfileobj

url = 'http://example.com/tarball.tar.gz'
headers = {'Cookie': 'oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie'}
with closing(urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request(url, headers=headers))) as response, \
     open(os.path.join('/data', url.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]), 'wb') as output_file:
    copyfileobj(response, output_file)
```

The code does not load the whole file into memory and therefore it may support large files. It doesn't check `Content-Length` header i.e., you may get partial file if the download is interrupted prematurely.